# Opening list from text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a text file which looks something like this:

```
["someString",1234,True],["anotherString",5678,False]
```

I am trying to convert the content of the file to a list, like this:

```
[["someString",1234,True],["anotherString",5678,False]]
```

So I tried to do this with the following lines:

```
test = open('file.txt','r')
test = test.read()
```

But this converts it to a string, like this:

```
'["someString",1234,True],["anotherString",5678,False]'
```

How can I convert this to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the string in brackets and use `ast.literal_eval` to parse it:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval

>>> testString = '["someString",1234,True],["anotherString",5678,False]'

>>> literal_eval("[" + testString + "]")
[['someString', 1234, True], ['anotherString', 5678, False]]
```

Comment: Do you know why `json.loads('[' + testString + ']')` fails?

Comment: @Vlad `False` is not a JSON keyword; `false` is however.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that.